# In the Eclipse IDE, how do I display the Hover values in Hex and not decimal?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to change the format of the data shown when I hold the mouse cursor over a variable (i.e., Hovers as Eclipse calls them)?  The format is Decimal, but I would like to change them to Hex, Octal, or Binary if that is possible?  Under Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Hovers there is nothing about the format.  Perhaps there is a way to hack a configuration file or something??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

If viewing in the register view, there is a down arrow triangle in the upper right that has Number Format on the drop down menu. If you select the rows first, it will apply to all of them. Also, eclipse preferences (window->preferences->c/c++->debug lets you set all displays permanently. However, it appears that this has been moved in eclipse neon and I can't find it anymore @#$%$%^$@!~

Comment: In Oxygen switching using the triangle set it permanently for me (at least project-wide, probably even workspace-wide)